# Are Force users more resilient than others?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

After re-watching a few parts of *Episode 3* and watching *The Bad Batch* I noticed something. Usually if a character takes a blaster hit (and is not the protagonist) they are dead. When the Jedi get gunned down though they seem to take multiple hits and are most often still able to fight after the first few hits (in both instances it was even shown with Jedi getting hit in the background of the scene and still fighting on).

Is that just pure coincidence or are Force users way more resilient than non Force users?

Edit: I'm talking about direct hits that are going onto more vital regions like stomach, under the shoulderblade,... (krennec also got hit once and survived but it was shoulder, also a few shots into the feet are things even normal ppl survived).

Comment: [Krennic got shot and survived](https://youtu.be/pspjFk8tS-M?t=81)

Comment: @Valorum good point will calrify there (the hits  I meant were torso hits,... not far shoulder shots or scratches like krennic)

Comment: I'm assuming a significant Force user would be moved by the Force to avoid lethal shots, even if they couldn't avoid getting hit in the first place.

Comment: @Valorum canans master took a few hits right into her armpit and still stood and fought with her lightsaber (as best example). so its not just moving she got hit and still stood

Comment: I expect the Force told her where to stand in the first place

Comment: "a character takes a blaster hit (and is not the protagonist) they are dead" This is called plot armor (in the case of the protagonist).

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is Yes, Force users are more resilient than average people. This is for multiple reasons.

1. Force users, especially Jedi, tend to have rigorous physical training to improve their strength and endurance. This would make them more likely to survive a blaster shot, or even not get hit in the first place.
2. The Force sustains, allowing users to survive things that they shouldn't. Darth Maul is a great example, but so is Anakin every time he jumps off a building and the clones have to follow with rappling cords or jetpacks.
3. Armor helps. In Episode 3 the clones and droids are trained to kill each other, and so aim for weak points in their armor. Once the Empire takes over, stormtrooper armor is basically useless so the whole thing is a weak point. Compared to what the Old Republic used, they might as well not be armored. Star Wars Rebels mentioned this point when some old clones join the rebels to help out against the Empire. Jedi like Anakin or Obi-Wan in Episode 2 and 3 wore armor, even if it was not full armor plating.
4. Plot Armor - Yes, this is out of universe, but the movies and shows tend to focus Force users. Having your main character die because they were shot in a dangerous situation is disappointing, but having them survive and escape is a considered a thrilling story. Fennic in The Mandolorian is a good example here.

Comment: Eh, I don't buy #1. No amount of exercise is doing to make your skin or organs impervious to superheated plasma. #2 is more about agility (and possibly some degree of self-levitation) than physical stamina.

Comment: @chepner - The Force absolutely can and is used to enhance all sorts of physical abilities. Darth Maul survived being cut in half through the power of the Force, for instance. It is also why a 2-foot-tall, 900-year-old gremlin can lock lightsabers with a middle-aged human Sith Lord without being tossed around like a rag doll.

Comment: @Adamant #1 is though stating it is the training itself. But doesn't hold up there as clones also got training...and I dare say so more physical training than jedis as they had no meditation sessions like them. And still died by a single blaster shot.